# LWP::UserAgent, mod_perl causing large Apache error logs

Tags: perl, apache, ubuntu, mod-perl, lwp

Each time LWP::UserAgent or LWP::Simple is used with mod_perl (PerlRun), Ubuntu 10.04.4 and Apache 2.2.14 I get about 50 or so error messages in the Apache error log:

> Constant subroutine ModPerl::ROOT::ModPerl::PerlRun::home_user_public_html_index_2ecgi::RC_NOT_IMPLEMENTED redefined at /usr/lib/perl5/ModPerl/Util.pm line 69.

I have attempted defining the functions I will be using as:

> use LWP::UserAgent qw(agent request);

However I am still getting these error messages. They are filling up the Apache error log very fast.

Comment: This isn't a programming question. Consider asking this on SuperUser.

Comment: @weberc2 - how is this not a programming question?  He's writing perl code.

Comment: I thought he was using an existing apache module. I misunderstood, my mistake.

Comment: @webrc2: If the comments aren't relevant, please delete them, and then djechlin can delete his and I can delete this.

Comment: Well I am using the standard Perl modules from CPAN, using the Perl, Apache, mod_perl Debian packages that come with Ubuntu 10 server. I have pinpointed the problem to this module (commenting out the code removes the errors). The code works fine though and I don't get any internal server error messages. I need to use this code. Perhaps a bug

Comment: Try posting a small complete script that exhibits the warning.

Comment: @James: I tried to reproduce your problem and couldn't do it. Please provide a stripped-down example script and your mod_perl configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I think  no warnings 'redefine'; will work.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
no warnings 'redefine';
```

Is how I usually do it.

Comment: However, "what if" `RC_NOT_IMPLEMENTED` hold different values for LWP and ModPerl?!

Comment: I'm till getting about 50 or so error messages when using this. Lots of messages like 'RC_ACCEPTED' redefined. It's filling up my error logs several GB per hour, not so healthy.